# jquery panel design in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I want to design a asp.net panel.Already created it but but theme is not working.Please help me.What should be in the

> script type="text/javascript"  tag?

Code is below

```
<script src="ui/jquery.corners.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="ui/jquery.ui.core.js "type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<asp:Panel ID='jQueryBox' runat='server' ClientIDMode='Static'
    class='rounded'>
  <p>Some Developer Links</p>
  <ol>
    Some thing

  </ol>
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: @ nunespascal (theme)...i have edited the question

Comment: @user1927791 You do not have include the them css ! how do you expect to work with out it ?

Comment: @user1927791 If you include it, then is probably not find it, debug with your browser tools to see if its loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can make any div (including a Panel) look nicer by applying [jQuery UI CSS classes](http://ui-dev.jquery.com/docs/Theming/API) to it. In particular, you'd need `ui-widget` on the outer div and `ui-widget-header` on an inner div. Eg:

```
<asp:Panel ID='jQueryBox' runat='server' ClientIDMode='Static' CssClass='ui-widget'>    
    <div class="ui-widget-header">Some Developer Links</div>
    <div class="ui-widget-content">
        <ol>
            <li>All of your content in here!</li>
        </ol>
    </div>
```